# Log exception: comparison of Fixnum with :debug failed in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created an application in Rails 3.2, generated a controller page, added a default route, removed the public/index.html file and get the following error when navigating '/'.

```
Internal Server Error
comparison of Fixnum with :debug failed
```

Detailed log: https://gist.github.com/1698521

Basically what the error is raised when adding the severity.

```
activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/buffered_logger.rb:80

def add(severity, message = nil, progname = nil, &block)
  @log.add(severity, message, progname, &block)
end
```

Any ideas of why this is might be happening?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I set wrong the log level in an initializer:

```
Rails.logger.level = :debug
```

The issue is that the Logger class internally compares the attribute level with a Fixnum and that was the mistake, that I put a symbol.
It should be done this way:

```
Rails.logger.level = 0
```

And, of course @Wilhelm is right about the best practice of defining root in the controller

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen that error but you should be using:
root :to => 'pages#demo'
instead of 
get '/' => 'pages#demo'
in your routes file.

Comment: Yes, that is a good practice, thumbs up, but it is not what caused the error.